# Computing Markov chain state on a 2x2 matrix

Tags: markov-chains

I have the following Markov matrix $A=\begin{bmatrix}
 1-\beta & \beta \\
 \alpha & 1-\alpha \\ 
 \end{bmatrix} $

And initial row vector $X_0 = (0,1)$

I need to compute the state vector $X_3$ which means $X_0 A^3 $.
I started doing it but got a very complex expression with $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

Is there any trick that I'm missing here that could make my life easier ?

Comment: It should be complicated.

Comment: It's often useful to diagonalize matrices when computing large powers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general formula for calculating the state state vector is of a Markov Chain with two states $\mathbb{X}=\{A,B\}$ (A,B are the states, not to be confused with  $a,b$ the probability values in your transition matrix):

$$\begin{equation}(\pi_{n}(A),\pi_{n}(B))=(\pi_{n}(A),\pi_{n}(B))P^{n}
\end{equation}$$

In order to calculate $P^{n}$ for any value of $n$ we can diagonalise matrix $P$.The characteristic equation $|\lambda I-P|=0$ of $P$ has eigenvalues $\lambda_{1}=1$ and $\lambda_{2} = 1-(b+a)$ (a,b) from your matrix.

The according eigenvectors are : $$u_{1}= \begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
1 
\end{pmatrix}$$ and $$u_{2}= \begin{pmatrix}
-b \\
a 
\end{pmatrix}.$$ Therefore $$P = \begin{pmatrix}
1 &-b\\
1 &a
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
1 &0\\
0 &\lambda_{2}
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
1 &-b\\
1 &a
\end{pmatrix}^{-1}.$$

So we have $$P^{n} = \begin{pmatrix}
1 &-b\\
1 &a
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
1^n &0\\
0 &\lambda_{2}^n
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
1 &-b\\
1 &a
\end{pmatrix}^{-1} = \frac{1}{b+a}\begin{pmatrix}
a+b \lambda_{2}^n &  b- \lambda_{2}^n  \\
a-a \lambda_{2}^n  & b+ \lambda_{2}^n  
\end{pmatrix}$$

Substituting in the first equation we take : $$(\pi_{n}(A),\pi_{n}(B))=\left( \frac{a}{b+a},\frac{b}{b+a}  \right) + \lambda_{2}^n \frac{b \pi_{0}(A) - a \pi_{0}(B)}{b+a}(1,-1)$$